# React Native Webgl Flickering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webgl

I am working on a React Native application that includes a WebGL section, using React Native WebGL (https://github.com/react-community/react-native-webgl)

I am having an issue with flickering when rendering. I suspect this is an issue to do with swapping the buffers in the WebGLView that RN WebGL uses and the actual framebuffer of the device.

Looking at the examples on the RN WebGL GitHub page none of them seem to properly implement rendering beyond more than just a single frame, or using a third party library such as Three.js.

I'm using requestAnimationFrame() to schedule the next frame to be rendered, and ending my frame update with gl.flush() and rngl.endFrame().

Below is my simplified code for updating each frame.

```
const update = () => {
        this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        this.gl.viewport(0, 0, this.gl.drawingBufferWidth, this.gl.drawingBufferHeight);

        this.shader.Bind(this.gl);

        let p = this.shader.GetAttribLocation(this.gl, "p");
        if (p > -1) {
            this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(p);
            this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);
            this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(p, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        }

        // Draw entities
        this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        this.gl.getError(); // Removing this prevents any rendering at all....
        this.gl.flush();
        this.rngl.endFrame();
        this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(update);
    };
```

A video of the flickering can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IyMMfnXVFo

As stated in the code, there is a call to gl.getError();, if I remove this call then there is no rendering at all, which is extremely peculiar.

Any help would be much appreciated